# Paint and Drag&Drop in Android

Tags: android, image, path, drag-and-drop, paint

Thanks for the reply, I think I did not explain well, what I wanted was to draw and paint on the same canvas. In the code below, I'm trying to drag "mBitmap" but I can not :(

```
class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private Bitmap mBitmap;
private ViewThread mThread;
private Path path = new Path();

private final int paintColor = Color.BLACK;
private Paint drawPaint;

private int mX;
private int mY;

public Panel(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    mThread = new ViewThread(this);
    setupPaint();
}

public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int ancho = canvas.getWidth();
    int largo = canvas.getHeight();
    paint.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
    canvas.drawLine(0, (largo/2), ancho, (largo/2), paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mX, mY, null);
    canvas.drawPath(path, drawPaint);
}
private void setupPaint() {
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (!mThread.isAlive()) {
        mThread = new ViewThread(this);
        mThread.setRunning(true);
        mThread.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (mThread.isAlive()) {
        mThread.setRunning(false);
    }
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float pointX = event.getX();
    float pointY = event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    postInvalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Sorry but I do not understand well. If anyone can guide me I appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to get you started:

**DragDropLinearLayout.java**

```
package com.example.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class DragDropLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    private static final String TAG = DragDropLinearLayout.class.getSimpleName();

    private boolean dragging = false;
    private View draggedView = null;

    private float touchX, touchY;

    public DragDropLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DragDropLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View v, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(v, index, params);

        v.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                dragging = true;
                draggedView = v;

                Log.d(TAG, "Dragging started!");
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

        if (dragging) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(touchX - draggedView.getWidth(), touchY - draggedView.getHeight());
            canvas.scale(1.5f, 1.5f);
            canvas.clipRect(0, 0, draggedView.getWidth(), draggedView.getHeight());
            draggedView.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchX = event.getX();
                touchY = event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;
        }

        return dragging || super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void onDragComplete() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                dragging = false;
                onDragComplete();

                invalidate();
                Log.d(TAG, "Dragging stopped!");

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchX = event.getX();
                touchY = event.getY();

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touchX = event.getX();
                touchY = event.getY();

                if (dragging) {
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    invalidate();
                }

                break;
        }

        return dragging || super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.views.DragDropLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</com.example.views.DragDropLinearLayout>
```

**What this does**

This example uses a custom `LinearLayout` implementation called `DragDropLinearLayout`. It allows you to drag and drop the single ImageView added to the LinearLayout.

**How this works**

All of the heavy lifting is done by `DragDropLinearLayout`. What `DragDropLinearLayout` does is it first adds a OnLongClickListener to all children added to it. The listener marks any view that is currently being long clicked as the view that is currently being dragged.

It also has touch listeners so that it can determine where the user is currently dragging the view. It finally draws a clone of the view being dragged at where the user's finger is.